# Cannot ping to localhost and any host into Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I'm connecting to server (Ubuntu) with ssh and I try to ping to localhost `127.0.0.1` or google.com, bitbucket.org, 8.8.8.8 but it doesn't work

```
ping 127.0.0.1

PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
308 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 309454ms
```

ping to bitbucket

```
ping bitbucket.org

PING bitbucket.org (104.192.143.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- bitbucket.org ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3024m
```

to google

```
ping google.com

ping: unknown host google.com
```

here is my host file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       odoo9-test      odoo9-test.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

104.192.143.2 bitbucket.org
```

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.1.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.10.1.103
```

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8069
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
....
```

and `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all` is set to 0

I'm newbie in server&network and I researchd many links regards to my issue but cannot find out how to resolve this, please help me

Comment: What does ifconfig give you? [Ubunut 16.04 - Network Configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html)

Answer (score 1):

You drop all input traffic except tcp port 22, 80, 8069.

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
```

Setting the whole policy to `drop` is not recommended, unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Actually, the default policy must be *drop*, but you need to know which ports you are going to need in order not to close them.

Comment: I added https but still cannot ping to bitbucket.org (it return error Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Connection timed out when run git pull )

Comment: Because ping and HTTP-requests are two completely different pair of socks. If you want to ping, you need to allow ICMP.

Comment: You 're right, I can't ping if ICMP is not added in iptables but why can't I run git pull although port 443 is added and my git repo is https://